# MySQL WHERE clause selects values then omits some based on another column?

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause

I have a pretty simple question (I think) but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. I'm sure I'm over-thinking this but I would like insight nonetheless.

Using MySQL, I would like to `SELECT` rows in a table based on a column using a `WHERE` clause and then refine that search based on another column. More specifically, I would like to return all entries from a specific user that haven't yet been archived.

Here is what I have today:

`"SELECT * FROM entries WHERE user_id = '4' AND archived <> 'yes'";`

This is not working so I tried:

`"SELECT * FROM entries WHERE (user_id = '4' AND archived <> 'yes')";`

But that hasn't worked either.

Do I need to return all the entries from that user and then remove from that array all of the entries that have an 'archive' value of 'yes' with a for loop or something using my scripting language?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: do you get any results from `SELECT * FROM entries WHERE user_id = '4'`?

Comment: Can you include the table structure by running DESC entries? As well as a couple of rows you expect to be selected. In theory the query would work fine - the first and second ones are identical, the parenthesis are unnecessary in this context.

Comment: Both queries are similar, parenthesis does not make any difference in the second query.

Comment: @Soujirou All of the entries are returned

Comment: @dbadness I remove my answer. Plead show your query in sqlfiddle

Comment: Here's the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b71fb/1 which is working just fine...

Comment: it also works fine with your `archived <>  'yes'` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6782/1  -- this means there's something wrong with your live data

Comment: @pala_ Yeah that's what I meant... I'll have to check my DB config and see if there's some updating to be done. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Try using `not like '%yes%'`. If that works you have extra characters in the field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are `NULL` values in the `archived` column, then those rows will not satisfy the inequality predicate. (It's the ages old issue of boolean three-valued logic... `TRUE`, `FALSE` and `NULL`.)

There's a couple of ways to deal with `NULL` values, to get those returned.

As one option, you could make use the (MySQL specific) NULL-safe comparison operator: **`<=>`**.

For example:

```
... WHERE user_id = '4' AND NOT (archived <=> 'yes')
```

That's effectively equivalent to the more ANSI-standard compliant:

```
... WHERE user_id = '4' AND (archived <> 'yes' OR archived IS NULL)
```

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to

Comment: That's totally what it was - I should've put that the `archived` column is either `yes` or `NULL` but kudos if you picked that up in the sqlfiddle. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: @dbadness: I didn't see a SQL Fiddle in your question. When we aren't provided information about whether a column is defined as NOT NULL, then we just have to assume that at some point there's going to be row that contains a NULL. And the equality and inequality comparisons to a `NULL` *always* yield `NULL`. (SQL has three-valued boolean logic: the result of a boolean expression can be TRUE, it can be FALSE or it can be NULL.)

Answer (score 0):

one idea is to change the yes or no answer to a 0/1 true false statement.
Make it so your archived are set to 0 and the default is 1 so then you could do

```
$query = <<<SQL
   SELECT id,title,name,etc 
   FROM entries 
   WHERE user_id = :id 
   AND archived = :true
SQL;
   $results = $this->dbconn->prepare( $query );
   $results->execute( array (
       ':id'  => $_GET['id'],
       ':true'=> 1,
    ));
   if($results->rowCount() < 1) 
   {
   echo "No Unarchived for this user";
   }
   else {
    //Pull Unarchived Data
   }
```

You didn't have any actual PHP so if you're unfamiliar with what I've posted it's PDO and I recommend reading into it.